# Ambiguous column name and I need it in he answer

Tags: database, view, ambiguous

I've written a program with 2 views. but, I'm getting the error msg: Ambiguous column name 'b_id'.
And, I need the b_id in the result. What can I do?

The code is as follows:

--view for all store managers with b_id and jobtitle

```
 CREATE VIEW storemanagers
 AS
 SELECT b_id, jobTitle,e_firstname,e_middlename,e_lastname
 FROM Employee
 WHERE jobTitle='Store Manager'
```

----view for employee in each branch

```
   CREATE VIEW employee_perbranch
   AS
   SELECT b_id, COUNT(*) AS 'Employee_count'
   FROM Employee
   GROUP BY b_id
```

--Procedure for listing store managers who manage a branch with more than 8 employees

```
  SELECT*
  FROM employee_perbranch
    SELECT e_firstname, e_middlename, e_lastname, Employee_count,b_id
    FROM storemanagers sm, employee_perbranch eb, Branch b
    WHERE   b.b_id=sm.b_id
    AND   eb.b_id=b.b_id
    AND   eb.Employee_Count >8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify an alias for `b_id` column from `SELECT e_firstname, e_middlename, e_lastname, Employee_count,b_id`, either `b.b_id` or `sm.b_id` as it's present in both views.